# Distance formula between two points in a list

Tags: python, math

I need to take a list I have created and find the closest two points and print them out. How can I go about comparing each point in the list?

There isn't any need to plot or anything, just compare the points and find the closest two in the list.

```
import math # 'math' needed for 'sqrt'

# Distance function
def distance(xi,xii,yi,yii):
    sq1 = (xi-xii)*(xi-xii)
    sq2 = (yi-yii)*(yi-yii)
    return math.sqrt(sq1 + sq2)

# Run through input and reorder in [(x, y), (x,y) ...] format
oInput = ["9.5 7.5", "10.2 19.1", "9.7 10.2"] # Original input list (entered by spacing the two points).
mInput = [] # Manipulated list
fList = [] # Final list
for o in oInput:
    mInput = o.split()
    x,y = float(mInput[0]), float(mInput[1])
    fList += [(x, y)] # outputs [(9.5, 7.5), (10.2, 19.1), (9.7, 10.2)]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is more convenient to rewrite your `distance()` function to take two `(x, y)` tuples as parameters:

```
def distance(p0, p1):
    return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)
```

Now you want to iterate over all pairs of points from your list `fList`.  The function `iterools.combinations()` is handy for this purpose:

```
min_distance = distance(fList[0], fList[1])
for p0, p1 in itertools.combinations(fList, 2):
    min_distance = min(min_distance, distance(p0, p1))
```

An alternative is to define `distance()` to accept the pair of points in  a single parameter

```
def distance(points):
    p0, p1 = points
    return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)
```

and use the `key` parameter to the built-in `min()` function:

```
min_pair = min(itertools.combinations(fList, 2), key=distance)
min_distance = distance(min_pair)
```

Comment: As a premature optimization, when only comparing like this there's no need to actually compute the square root.

Comment: that seems to work. sadly, I'll have to find a different way of doing it since it is for homework and our use of different libraries and functions is very limited. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @unwind: The overhead of calculating the square root is MUCH less then comparing bigger integers, especially with more points.

Comment: @morcutt: All of Sven's code uses methods from the python standard library. Even if you can't use them, they are good to know about.

Comment: I'd recommend a refactor in the last snippet using a pretty common pattern that avoids repeating the key function: min((distance(*pair), pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(fList, 2))[1]. Moreover using a generator you can define distance()'s signature how you want.

Comment: @nutcracker: Huh? the distance calculation has to be done for every pair of points, so n*(n-1)/2 calls; it almost certainly **is** dominating the time for this algorithm, **especially** when there are many points. That's why it should be removed from the iteration, by comparing distance-squared's.

Comment: ... or may not be significant, since it is a single call to a C function. I'm used to doing this algorithm in a compiled language, where math.sqrt would be dominating the time per loop.

Answer (score 12):

I realize that there are library constraints on this question, but for completeness if you have `N` points in an Nx2 numpy ndarray (2D system):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
x = numpy.array([[9.5,7.5],[10.2,19.1],[9.7,10.2]])
mindist = numpy.min(pdist(x))
```

I always try to encourage people to use numpy/scipy if they are dealing with data that is best stored in a numerical array and it's good to know that the tools are out there for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `math.sqrt` function is both slow and, in this case, unnecessary.  Try comparing the distance squared to speed it up (sorting distances vs. distance squared will always produce the same ordering):

```
def distSquared(p0, p1):
    return (p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fixed code. No efficient algorithm, just the brute force one.

```
import math # math needed for sqrt

# distance function
def dist(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p2[1] - p1[1]) ** 2)

# run through input and reorder in [(x, y), (x,y) ...] format
input = ["9.5 7.5", "10.2 19.1", "9.7 10.2"] # original input list (entered by spacing the two points)
points = [map(float, point.split()) for point in input] # final list

# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points
mindist = float("inf")
for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(points, 2):
    if dist(p1, p2) < mindist:
        mindist = dist(p1, p2)
        closestpair = (p1, p2)

print(closestpair)
```

Comment: Why the `p1 != p2` comparison?  I think if a point appears twice in the list, the minimum distance is supposed to be 0.

Comment: I think the `p1 != p2` is in there because of not understanding what `itertools.combinations` returns. If you were brute force looping through the `points` twice (i.e for p1 in points: for p2 in points:) then you would need that to avoid considering the distance from a point to itself.

Comment: Nope. It was in there before I put in the `itertools.combinations`. I just realize this stupid mistake :D It was in there because I was looping with two for loops.

Comment: For completeness, if someone has the same limitation of OP, that they have to not use itertools (perhaps to demonstrate their understanding of how to find all the combinations), the alternative code with **nested** loops could be: `for i in range(len(points) - 1):`  `p1 = points[i]` `for j in range(i+1, len(points)):` `p2 = points[j]` .. and then continue from there.

Comment: ... And, as for other solutions, it would be higher performance to avoid the sqrt, just compare distance-squareds. Though maybe that doesn't matter in an interpreted language, since it is a single call to a C function. (I'm used to programming in C# or C++, where it makes a big difference.)

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
oInput = ["9.5 7.5", "10.2 19.1", "9.7 10.2"]

# parse inputs
inp = [(float(j[0]), float(j[1])) for j in [i.split() for i in oInput]]

# initialize results with a really large value
min_distance = float('infinity')
min_pair = None

# loop over inputs
length = len(inp)
for i in xrange(length):
    for j in xrange(i+1, length):
        point1 = inp[i]
        point2 = inp[j]

        if math.hypot(point1[0] - point2[0], point1[1] - point2[0]) < min_distance:
            min_pair = [point1, point2]
```

once the loops are done, min_pair should be the pair with the smallest distance.

Using float() to parse the text leaves room for improvement.

math.hypot is about a third faster than calculating the distance in a handwritten python-function

Answer (score 0):

First, some notes:

```
a**2 # squares a
(xi - xii)**2 # squares the expression in parentheses.
```

mInput doesn't need to be declared in advance.
`fList.append((x, y))` is more pythonic than using `+=`.

Now you have `fList`. Your distance function can be rewritten to take 2 2-tuple (point) arguments, which I won't bother with here.

Then you can just write:

```
shortest = float('inf')
for pair in itertools.combinations(fList, 2):
    shortest = min(shortest, distance(*pair))
```

Comment: "*fList.append((x, y)) is more pythonic than using +=*"  gee, I liked the `+=`. Didn't know it applied to list elements. What's unpythonic about using that operator?

Comment: BTW, this finds the distance itself, but doesn't remember WHICH points yielded that distance. Re original question: "*find the closest two points and print them out*"

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: With `a_list += something`, something must be a list. It's awkward to put square brackets around stuff just so you can append it to a list. On your second comment, that's true. It should be pretty simple to extend this to actually answer the question, but as written it doesn't quite do it.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the above questions suggest finding square root using `math.sqrt` which is slow as well as not a good approach to find square root. In spite of using such approach just recall the basic concepts from school: think of taking the square root of any positive number, x. The square root is then written as a power of one-half: x½. Thus, a fractional exponent indicates that some root is to be taken.

so rather than using `math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)`

Use

```
def distance(a,b):
  euclidean_distance = ((b[0]-a[0])**2 + (a[1]-a[1])**2)**0.5
  return(euclidean_distance)
```

Hope it helps