# Sprite collide with object function?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

Is it possible for me to create a function where it displays a message if the Sprite (Rocket) collides with the astroid objects?

```
class Rocket(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.image=Rocket.image
        self.firecountdown = 0

    def setup(self):
        self.rect.x=700
        self.rect.y=random.randint(20,380)

    def updateposition(self):
        self.rect.x=self.rect.x-1
        time.sleep(0.005)

        if self.rect.x == 0 :
            self.rect.x = 700 + random.randint(0, 100)
            self.rect.y=random.randint(20,380)


asteroids=[]

asteroidsize=[]

for i in range(25):

        x=random.randrange(700,10000)

        y=random.randrange(0,400)

        asteroids.append([x,y])

        asteroids[i]=Asteroid()

for i in range(25):

        asteroidsize.append(random.randint(6,15))


while True:

        for i in range(len(asteroids)):


        pygame.draw.circle(screen,GREY,asteroids[i],asteroidsize[i])


        asteroids[i][0]-=2



        if asteroids[i][0]<0:

            y=random.randrange(0,400)

            asteroids[i][1]=y

            x=random.randrange(700,720)

            asteroids[i][0]=x
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, i should have worded it better-Would you be able to tell/show me how this could be done?

Comment: No, this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. I suggest you start with [`pygame`'s documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function on your Rocket class that checks for collisions. Since the asteroids are circles, you'll want to check if the closest point on the circle to the center of your sprite's rect is within the rect's bounds:

```
def check_asteroid_collision( self, asteroid, size ) :
    # Create a vector based on the distance between the two points
    distx   = self.rect.centerx - asteroid[0];
    disty   = self.rect.centery - asteroid[1];
    # Get magnitude (sqrt of x^2 + y^2)
    distmag = ((distx * distx) + (disty * disty)) ** 0.5;

    # Get the closest point on the circle:
    # Circle center + normalized vector * radius
    clsx    = asteroid[0] + distx / distmag * size;
    clsy    = asteroid[1] + disty / distmag * size;

    # Check if it's within our rect
    if self.rect.collidepoint( clsx, clsy ) :
        # We're colliding!! Do whatever
        print( "Oh no!" );
```

Then in your game loop, you could check collisions by calling this:

```
while True:
    for i in range(len(asteroids)):
        ...
        # Collision checking
        myrocket.check_asteroid_collision( asteroids[i], asteroidsize[i] );
```

Keep in mind this process is somewhat expensive and it will check every asteroid if it's colliding. If there's a large number of asteroids, it'll run slowly.

Answer (score 0):

While I dont code python I can give you a simple example of how to accomplish something like this.

1. Make all your game objects inherit from a general game item class, this way you know all items have a position and a collision radius.

   `class: 
      int positionX
      int positionY
      int radius`
2. Then keep all your items in a global list of game objects.
3. Loop over your game list and see if any two items collide

   `foreach object1 in gameObjectsList:
      foreach object2 in gameObjectsList:
          if(object1 != object2)
             if(math.sqrt(object1.positionX - object2.positionX)**2 + 
               (object1.positionY - object2.positionY)**2) 
               <= object1.radius + object2.radius.
                   //Things are colliding`
4. As the game progresses make sure you keep the position variables updated in each object.

What this means is basically that you have your list of game objects, and you loop over these every game frame and check if any of them are touching each other.

Or in terms of pure math, use the distance formula ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407969/distance-formula-between-two-points-in-a-list)) to get the distance between the two items, and then check if their combined radius is greater than this distance. If it is they are touching.

Comment: [`pygame.sprite`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) actually implement collision detection for you, and provide the position etc.

Comment: Well assuming it dosent have a physics simulation, or a polygon interpreter it is doing something close to this, although probably somewhat optimized. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately, `pygame.sprite` only supports collision detection for rect to rect or circle to circle between other `pygame.sprite`s. If you want to do collision detection between a sprite and a non-sprite, or between rects and circles, you'd need to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, making the score is possible. I am asuming you know the sprite collision function : `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`. If you don't, look into the PyGame Docs. or google it. But here is how you do it. First. add these lines of code at the beginning of your code after the `pygame,init()` line:

```
variable = 0
variable_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
variable_surf = variable_font.render(str(variable), 1, (0, 0, 0))
variable_pos = [10, 10]
```

Clearly, `variable` can be a string, just remove the `str()` in line 3. Line 1 is self-explanatory - it is the value you will see on the screen (just the stuff after the `=` sign and/or the parantheses). Line 2 decides what **font and size** you want the message to be in. If you choose `None and 50`, it means that you want the message in a normal font and in size 50. The third line **renders, or pastes,** the message on the screen the name of the variable that contains the **string/number**, the number **1** (I have no idea why), and the **color** your message will be. If the variable contains a number, put a `str()` around it. The last line will be the position of the message. But you will need to blit it first. To prevent the message from appearing on the screen forever, make a variable:

```
crashed = 0
```

Then make your instances and groups:

```
ship = Rocket(None)
asteroids = pygame.sprite.Group() #This is recommended, try making a class for the asteroids
```

And finally your collision code:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Rocket, asteroids, True):
    crashed = 1
```

You can make your blits controlled with the `crashed` variable:

```
if crashed == 0:
    screen.blit(ship.image, ship.rect)
elif crashed == 1:
    screen.blit(ship.image, ship.rect)
    screen.blit(variable_surf, variable_pos)
```

The last blit line will blit your message on the screen at the location listed (variable_pos) when your ship crashes (`crashed = 1` in the collision code). You can use make some code to make `crashed` back to 0. Remember to do `pygame.display.flip()` or weird stuff will happen. I hope this answer helps you!